# Java's FilterOutputStream adds a performance penalty

Tags: java, performance

I have a piece of code that's splitting an output stream to two destinations.  They're both going to a file, but the second destination will go through a filter.  I'm trying to figure out why simply wrapping a FilterOutputStream without overriding any methods adds a huge performance penalty.

I created a file that's 358 megabytes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=dummyfile.txt count=700000 bs=512
```

Ran this code against it:

```
private OutputStream getFilteredStream(OutputStream out1, OutputStream out2) {
    return new TeeOutputStream(out1, new FilterOutputStream(out2));
}
private OutputStream getDestination(String name) {
    return new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
}
...
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("dummyfile.txt"));
OutputStream out = getFilteredStream(getDestination("dest1"), getDestination("dest2"));
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
out.flush();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.err.println(((end - start) / 1000.0) + " seconds");
// close the files
```

The result:

```
1.672 seconds
```

If I remove the FilterOutputStream...

```
private OutputStream getFilteredStream(OutputStream out1, OutputStream out2) {
    return new TeeOutputStream(out1, out2);
}
```

... and run it again, the result is:

```
0.797 seconds
```

I am expecting a performance penalty when using a FilterOutputStream, but I am NOT expecting the penalty to be double, especially when not overriding any methods.  I looked at the source code for FilterOutputStream, but did not see anything that would cause such a huge penalty.

Can someone explain what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Use a profiler to see what's happening.

Comment: What's the point of adding a plain `FilterOutputStream` to the pipeline, without subclassing it to do any actual filtering?

Comment: There is no point, I'm just trying to demonstrate the problem I'm seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is slower because the default implementation in `FilterOutputStream` disables block processing and sends all bytes through the `write(int b)` method, one at a time.

This is [**documented**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-):

> Note that this method does not call the write method of its underlying input stream with the same arguments. **Subclasses of FilterOutputStream should provide a more efficient implementation of this method**.

Comment: Indeed, after overriding the write(byte b[], int off, int len) method, the performance is back to normal.